# Programmatically Assign Connection Variables to initializeapp()

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire

I'm trying to allow the user to select which firebase project they connect to. My angularfire connection is made in the main ngmodule as outlined in the documentation:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [...],
  imports: [
    ...
    provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebase)), 
    provideAuth(() => getAuth()), 
    provideFirestore(() => getFirestore()), 
    provideStorage(() => getStorage())],
    ...
```

And that works. However, I don't want to load the connection options from the environment file and instead want the user to be able to choose what set of options they load. I've toyed with APP_INITIALIZER and have been able to load asynchronous data from a file prior to loading the app, however I now understand that, that data cannot be assigned to imports.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!